# ember-data: loading records in hasMany relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to code feature that allows logged-in users to add products to a "saved item" list.  The model is:

```
//saveditem.js model
export default DS.Model.extend({
    user: belongsTo('user'),
    product: belongsTo('product', { async: true }),
    dateAdded: attr('string')
});
```

On the `saveditems` route where the saved items are displayed, the `model()` hook is:

```
model() {
    return this.get("store").findAll('saveditem');
}
```

the api is returning records with JUST the ids:

```
{
    "dateAdded": "Mon, 11 Dec 2017 20:59:10 GMT",
    "id": 4458,
    "product": 4458,
    "user": "me"
},
{
    "dateAdded": "Sun, 10 Dec 2017 10:26:02 GMT",
    "id": 3657,
    "product": 3657,
    "user": "me"
}
...
```

**How can I get the hasMany relationship to load the actual products, using the IDs?**

Comment: What is it that is actually not working for you? Do you access product properties anywhere and do not see any API calls made? Or do you absolutely, positively want to load them with the saveditems before the products are needed (did you try `async: false` then)?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Your question helped me figure it out...posted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out (prompted by arne.b's question).  The setup was correct, but the way I was calling the items wasn't.

I was doing this in the template:

```
{{#each model as |result|}}
    <div>
    {{result.productName}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

Which printed empty divs because it's looping through my `saveditem` records, but the relationship wasn't resolving because I wasn't calling the product object itself.  The correct way:

```
{{#each model as |result|}}
    <div>
    {{result.product.productName}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

I also needed to set `async: true` on the model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({

    user: belongsTo('user'),
    product: belongsTo('product', { async: true }),
    dateAdded: attr('string')

});
```